# Heroku Flask app successful commit but receives "Application error"

Tags: python, opencv, flask, heroku

I have a Flask app that uses OpenCV to detect faces from a photo. I'm using Heroku with GitHub to make this site live but I keep receiving "Application error"

The most helpful tutorial I have found was https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/deploying-your-opencv-flask-web-application-on-heroku-c23efcceb1e8. Wherein I followed exactly what he did and still receive "Application error." But when I use his folders and scripts, his site goes live. But when I triple-check that everything I have in my documents matches his, my Flask app still receives "Application error"

**Directory tree** https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiqP7.png

Not sure what's going on, here's my most recent build log

#### Build log from Heroku

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Apt app detected
-----> Reusing cache
-----> Updating apt caches
       Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
       Hit:2 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease
       Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]
       Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
       Fetched 223 kB in 1s (317 kB/s)
       Reading package lists...
-----> Fetching .debs for libsm6
       Reading package lists...
       Building dependency tree...
       0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
       Need to get 0 B/16.1 kB of archives.
       After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
       Download complete and in download only mode
-----> Fetching .debs for libxrender1
       Reading package lists...
       Building dependency tree...
       0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
       Need to get 0 B/18.7 kB of archives.
       After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
       Download complete and in download only mode
-----> Fetching .debs for libfontconfig1
       Reading package lists...
       Building dependency tree...
       0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
       Need to get 0 B/114 kB of archives.
       After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
       Download complete and in download only mode
-----> Fetching .debs for libice6
       Reading package lists...
       Building dependency tree...
       0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
       Need to get 0 B/41.0 kB of archives.
       After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
       Download complete and in download only mode
-----> Installing libfontconfig1_2.13.1-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libice6_2%3a1.0.10-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libsm6_2%3a1.2.3-1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libxrender1_1%3a0.9.10-1_amd64.deb
-----> Writing profile script
-----> Rewrite package-config files
-----> Apt app detected
-----> Reusing cache
-----> Updating apt caches
       Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
       Hit:2 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease
       Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]
       Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
       Fetched 223 kB in 1s (349 kB/s)
       Reading package lists...
-----> Fetching .debs for libsm6
       Reading package lists...
       Building dependency tree...
       0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
       Need to get 0 B/16.1 kB of archives.
       After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
       Download complete and in download only mode
-----> Fetching .debs for libxrender1
       Reading package lists...
       Building dependency tree...
       0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
       Need to get 0 B/18.7 kB of archives.
       After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
       Download complete and in download only mode
-----> Fetching .debs for libfontconfig1
       Reading package lists...
       Building dependency tree...
       0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
       Need to get 0 B/114 kB of archives.
       After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
       Download complete and in download only mode
-----> Fetching .debs for libice6
       Reading package lists...
       Building dependency tree...
       0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
       Need to get 0 B/41.0 kB of archives.
       After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
       Download complete and in download only mode
-----> Installing libfontconfig1_2.13.1-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libice6_2%3a1.0.10-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libsm6_2%3a1.2.3-1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libxrender1_1%3a0.9.10-1_amd64.deb
-----> Writing profile script
-----> Rewrite package-config files
-----> Python app detected
 !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.8.8
       Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
-----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
-----> Apt app detected
-----> Reusing cache
-----> Updating apt caches
       Hit:1 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease
       Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
       Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]
       Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
       Fetched 223 kB in 1s (330 kB/s)
       Reading package lists...
-----> Fetching .debs for libsm6
       Reading package lists...
       Building dependency tree...
       0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
       Need to get 0 B/16.1 kB of archives.
       After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
       Download complete and in download only mode
-----> Fetching .debs for libxrender1
       Reading package lists...
       Building dependency tree...
       0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
       Need to get 0 B/18.7 kB of archives.
       After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
       Download complete and in download only mode
-----> Fetching .debs for libfontconfig1
       Reading package lists...
       Building dependency tree...
       0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
       Need to get 0 B/114 kB of archives.
       After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
       Download complete and in download only mode
-----> Fetching .debs for libice6
       Reading package lists...
       Building dependency tree...
       0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
       Need to get 0 B/41.0 kB of archives.
       After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
       Download complete and in download only mode
-----> Installing libfontconfig1_2.13.1-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libice6_2%3a1.0.10-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libsm6_2%3a1.2.3-1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libxrender1_1%3a0.9.10-1_amd64.deb
-----> Writing profile script
-----> Rewrite package-config files
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 188.3M
-----> Launching...
       Released v21
       https://lazereyes.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

#### app.py

```
import imghdr
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image
from os.path import join, dirname, realpath
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, abort
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import json

# Code...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=port)
```

#### requirements.txt

```
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
numpy==1.20.1
opencv-python==4.5.1.48
Pillow==8.1.2
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

#### Procfile

```
web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT app:app
```

#### runtime.txt

```
python-3.8.5
```

#### Aptfile

```
libsm6
libxrender1
libfontconfig1
libice6
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the exact error message, I can think of two issues:

1. You should check that the `FLASK_ENV`, `FLASK_APP` and `PORT` environment variables are set in Heroku.
2. You should check that the image running on Heroku uses a Python version, which is compatible with your code. In my case, this was the solution to a problem similar to yours.